# What is this weird file in my work directory?

Tags: git, qt

I found a weird file exist in my work directory with this name:

chillncode.h.Pj9704 (chillncode.h is one of my header files in my project)

I searched for that and I found nothing that be related to .Pj9704 format file. I wondered why there isn't another .Pj9704 or something like that for another header files in my work directory? But I guess this can be related to stuffs that I'm using, Qt or Git.

I opened this file with my text editor and I see there are my previous codes from chillncode.h in this file.

Comment: Doubt it's git. The extension might be randomly generated. Might by Qt, or a backup or lock file created by your text editor. What's the contents of the file?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I opened the file with notepad and I see previous version of my codes in chillncode.h

Comment: Some temporary file. Could be a backup from editor.